# Is it useful to learn the International Phonetic Alphabet in order to learn pronunciation?

Tags: learning-methods

I have always regarded phonetic transcriptions using the IPA, something only linguists learn and find useful. Would a normal language learner benefit from knowing the IPA when learning a new language and progress quicker?

Comment: See also http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/88/how-can-i-learn-ipa and http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/473/what-advantages-if-any-are-there-for-learning-the-ipa-when-studying-a-language